# Quelle est la différence entre « les gens » et « les personnes » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, société

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence ? Quand utilise-t-on l'un ou l'autre ? Est-ce que c'est similaire à la différence entre « people » et « persons » en anglais ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tout à fait, les "gens" représente un ensemble indivisible de personnes en nombre indéterminé. "Les gens" peut prendre deux formes communes, soit être synonyme de foule, soit utiliser pour définir les Hommes en général (ex: "Les gens d'ici sont méfiants").

Une personne représente un élément à part entière parmi "les gens". C'est un être humain sans sexe déterminé. On se servira du pluriel pour définir une ensemble de personnes parmi un ensemble plus grand.

ex1 : **Les personnes handicapés** disposent de places de parking plus larges.

ex2 : **Les personnes qui râlent** vivent plus longtemps.

Comment: Bonne réponse (+1). En effet, il est très rare de rencontrer *les personnes* sans aucun qualificatif, à l'inverse de l'expression *les gens* qui, bien qu'elle supporte divers qualificatifs possibles, se suffit à elle-même.

Comment: (Et, incidemment, je suis fier d'apprendre que je vais vivre vieux.) (^_^)

Answer (score 4):

La réponse de Kraiss est exacte, mais il manque un détail sur "Les gens"

*Les gens*, comme on peut le constater de par son déterminant, est un pluriel.
Son singulier est *la gent* (nom féminin).

*[la gent](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gent)* signifie un groupe de personnes caractérisé par un trait particulier.

*Les gens* sont donc une multitude de groupes de personnes, avec tout autant de particularités différentes, ce qui accentue la difficulté de pouvoir y attacher un qualitatif, par rapport à *des personnes*.